# Laravel Socialite class not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I need to set up social authentication in Laravel. I am using `Laravel Socialite` and it is not working at all. I am following the official github [documentation](https://github.com/laravel/socialite). However, I am facing `Class 'Socialite' not found` error. I don't really know why. I have even included `use Socialite;` at the top of before the class starts.

I have added the providers `Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,` and the facade `'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,`.

I used hacks like `composer dump-autoload`, `php artisan cache:clear` and `composer update` but to no avail.

I am using Socialite Version 3.0.7 and my Laravel version is 5.4.33.

I even tried using `use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;` but then I get `Target [Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory] is not instantiable.` error.

Comment: Ok, just run command `php artisan config:cache` and  `php artisan config:clear` to clear the catch of configuration and check

Comment: Make sure have socialite install correctly by checking package.json file and directory existence in vendor/laravel/socialite. Also, try to reinstall if it already.

Comment: @pritamBohra: Did you check that?

Comment: Maybe composer dumpautoload and clear application cache?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: When using `inline code` formatting, there is no value in using triple backticks - just use single ones. Triple-backticks are used elsewhere for block formatting, but they do not work here.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd yes, I tried that and it worked for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Please add this `'use Socialite;'` in your controller issue will resolve cause after installing packagist 'laravel/socialite' you might be not calling it in your controller.

Comment: please read the question completely. I have already mentioned that I have include  ```use Socialite;```. I need to downvote your answer, but couldn't.

Comment: @PritamBohra: it is probably better for you to assume that people making suggestions are doing so out of helpfulness. I will therefore downvote your question, not least for all the begging, but also for the churlishness on display here. Is this perhaps a learning moment?

Comment: @PritamBohra I will also downvote your question for sounding rude to someone who is only trying to assist you

Comment: @sunitiydav I am sorry for being rude :(